Converting Text Date & Time to Just Numeric Date
I have a report that includes a column with a text string for the date in the format "Nov  8, 2024 at 12:00AM EST". I am wanting to just extract the date and convert it to date format (for this example, 11/08/2024). I've tried looking and it looks like REGEXEXTRACT might work, but I can't figure out the right way to write out the formula. I tried =REGEXEXTRACT(R3,", ([A-Za-z \d]*)" ) and it just returns 2024 at 12. Is there a way this can be done with a simple formula? I've included a screenshot of what I'd like it to look like, where S column is where the formula would go.

If Google Sheets is anything like Excel, there's nothing to convert - the cell actually contains a number and it's only the cell format that determines how it looks.

As a general rule in StackOverflow, if your concern is solved, please accept an answer that works best for you by clicking the check mark beside the answer. This is to let other members of the community with the same concern as yours know that the issue is resolved. You may also upvote the other answers.


You may try:
=+split(A2," at",)



This is interesting. How does adding the + to the split function return only the first element of the result? I tried to search for the reference but I can't seem to find it. The SPLIT reference does not say anything about adding the + at the beginning. Usually I still use INDEX for this.

jus a shortcut to replicate index(<array/range>,1,1)

Assuming the text is in cell A1, you could try it by combining TEXT with REGEXEXTRACT and DATEVALUE.
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "([A-Za-z]{3}) (\d{1,2}), (\d{4})")), "MM/DD/YYYY")


I tested this answer and got DATEVALUE parameter 'Sep' cannot be parsed to date/time. I think that's because of the regex's output being Sep 18 2024. Shouldn't it be =JOIN(" ", REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "([A-Za-z]{3}) (\d{1,2}), (\d{4})")) so that it provides this sample output?

You may also try this:
=BYROW(Q2:Q, LAMBDA(a, IF(a="", "", REGEXEXTRACT(a, "^(.*) at"))))


This captures the date before at and returns them as a result.

OUTPUT

If you wish to format the date to something like mm/dd/yyyy, you may wrap REGEXEXTRACT(a, "^(.*) at") with TEXT:
=BYROW(Q2:Q, LAMBDA(a, IF(a="", "", TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(a, "^(.*) at"), "mm/dd/yyyy"))))

OUTPUT

REFERENCES

BYROW function
IF function
REGEXEXTRACT

